# Change column values into rating and sum

Tags: pandas

Change the column values and sum the row according to conditions.

```
d = {'col1': [20, 40], 'col2': [30, 40],'col3':[200,300}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


       col1  col2  col3
0     20     30    200
1     40     40    300

Col4 shoud give back the sum of the row after the values have been tranfered to a rating. 
Col1 Value between 0-20 ->2 Points, 20-40 -> 3 Points 
Col2 Value between 40-50 ->2 Points, 70-80 -> 3 Points 
Col3 Value between 0-100 ->2 Points, 100-300 -> 2 Points

    col 4 (Points)
0     2
1     6
```

Comment: Have a look at `pd.cut`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pd. cut as follows. Values didnt add up though. Happy to asist further if clarified.

pd.cut to bin and save in new columnms suffixed withname Points. Select only columns with string Points and add.

```
df['col1Points'],df['col2Points'],df['col3Points']=\
pd.cut(df.col1, [0,20,40],labels=[2,3])\
,pd.cut(df.col2, [40,70,80],labels=[2,3])\
,pd.cut(df.col3, [-0,100,300],labels=[2,3])
df['col4']=df.filter(like='Points').sum(axis=1)



 col1  col2  col3 col1Points col2Points col3Points  col4
0    20    30   200          2        NaN          3   5.0
1    40    40   300          3        NaN          3   6.0
```